# Selenium WebDriver C# -- XPath is not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

[image: Validation Message Source Code]

From the above code mentioned, if I use below XPath:

```
//*[contains(text(),'Error while adding Assessment Detail or You do not have permission to update record')]
```

The resulted data is showing invalid as shown below:

[image: Validation Output Image]

My requirement:

It should show (-) Expand But currently showing (+) which means only "div" and not inner content.

Please help me out with any solution!

Comment: What is your desire output ? which element you wanna select ?

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: The `XPath` plugin of Fire fox  can only to help to find the element of given xpath, rather than display the text content of the found element. The symbol: `(+)` at here just to tell you the found element has child nodes, you can click it to expand if you want to check the child nodes.  Please clarify your problem is want the found element expand automatically if has child nodes, or you want to get the text of the found element?   Finally, the `(+)` or `(-)` at here is not part of the element's text.

Comment: Good questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to improve yours providing real code and output text, not images.

Comment: When I am using Xpath://*[contains(text(),'Error while adding Assessment Detail or You do not have permission to update record')] it is showing just main class "k-notification-wrap" but rather my requirement is to show inside data "Error while adding Assessment Detail or You do not have permission to update record" with the use of above xpath.